# HBase database : Is it possible to filter on a column qualifier using Java API/REST API?

Tags: sql, database, filter, hbase, nosql

I'm completely new to HBase and I'm used to RDBMS database where I can use the **WHERE clause** to filter the records.
So, is there something similar to RDBMS using **Java API** or **REST API** exposed by HBase to filter the records using a **column qualifier**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

If you want to get only certain column qualifiers then you should use `addColumn(byte[] family, byte[] qualifier)` method of your [Get](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Get.html) or [Scan](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html) instances. This is the most efficient way to query qualifiers you need because only HBase Stores representing the specific columns in request need to be accessed. Example of usage:

```
Get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("rowKey"));
get.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("columnFamily", Bytes.toBytes("Qual"));

Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("columnFamily"), Bytes.toBytes("Qual1"));
scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("columnFamily"), Bytes.toBytes("Qual2"));
```

If you need more complicated tool to filter your qualifiers then you can use [QualifierFilter](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/QualifierFilter.html) class from Java API. Example how you can query all columns with certain qualifiers:

```
Filter filter = new QualifierFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
  new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("columnQual")));

Get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("rowKey"));
get.setFilter(filter);

Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setFilter(filter);
```

Also you can read about [another HBase filters](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/package-summary.html) and [how combine them](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FilterList.html) in official HBase documentation.